# What determines the close reason in the event of conflicts here?

Tags: support, closing

On the Trilogy, at least as far as I've been told, the stated close reason in the event of a tie is the earliest given reason in the majority. Example, if all 5 votes are different, the first one wins.

However, [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3769/best-video-game-quotes-closed) had at least 3 separate close reasons given in the sequence ABCB?. I cast the 3rd vote myself. By the logic of how the Trilogy operates, the B close reason should have been selected, but instead my close reason "Subjective & Argumentative" was selected (on which I assume the 5th vote was S&A but I don't exactly have proof).

What is the close reason logic that is used on this site?

Comment: I *think* I voted NaRQ, but I don't remember the first vote... I think it was S&A, are you sure it was something else?

Comment: Ah, I didn't want to reveal them, but A = Off-Topic, B = Not A Real Question. I hope you close voters don't mind me outing you.

Comment: I think your suspicion of the fifth vote being S&A is correct, the code base is the same as the original trilogy sites, so the same logic applies.

Comment: @Juan I'm pretty sure a minority vote wouldn't win, so it most likely had to be S&A, but unless RCIX outs the given reason we can only assume. Past that, the same logic as the trilogy would've dictated that "Not A Real Question" should've won.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the event of a tie, the **last** close vote will be used, e.g. in the following order

1. NaRQ
2. off-topic
3. NaRQ
4. off-topic
5. S&A

the question would be closed as off-topic.

The code has always been this way; I've updated the **[main meta FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-question/10583#10583)** with this correction (I blame me for not paying more attention to that FAQ area).